# Are the level lines of this submersion a trivial fibration?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $f$ be the function defined over $$\big\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4,\,x_1,x_2,x_3>0\big\} \setminus\big\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4,\,x_1=x_2=x_3+x_4\big\}$$ by

\begin{align*}
f(\boldsymbol{x})=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1x_2x_3 \\
x_1x_2x_4\\
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

One can prove that the level lines of $f$ associated to the values $(y_1,y_2,1)$, where $y_1>0,\,y_2>0$, are homeomorphic to the circle.

**Question:** Does there exist $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for $y_1\geq 0$ sufficiently small, $f$ restricted over $f^{-1}\big(\big\{(y_1,y_2,1),\,y_2\in[0,\varepsilon[ \big\}\big)$ is a trivial fibration?

Since $f$ is not proper, we cannot use Ehresmann's theorem. We only know that $f$ is a submersion since it's differential is

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{D}_{\boldsymbol{x}}f=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_2x_3 & x_1x_3 & x_1x_2 & 0 \\
x_2x_4 & x_1x_4 & 0 & x_1x_2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

and the domain on $f$ was chosen in adequacy.

Comment: (i) A fibration is a map. So, what do you mean by "the level lines [...] are a trivial fibration?" (ii) Since the map $f$ is rather simple, I think this problem can be restated in elementary terms.  If so, it would be good to have this presented. (iii) It could also help if you explain the motivation here. Is it an exercise from a textbook? If so, which exercise from which textbook?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I modified the question regarding your remark. This question is from my own research: I'm studying a family of dynamical systems over the simplex for which the invariant sets are homeomorphic to the circle (and are the level lines of a function $f$ as described). I'm wondering if the period of this system is a continuous function of the initial position: the continuity of the vector field is not sufficient, maybe a fibration property from $f$ can help to conclude.